# Avoiding temporary construction when returning by value and passing by const reference

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, copy-elision

I have a function which accepts a `Large` by const reference:

```cpp
void func(const Large& param);
```

and a class which holds a `Large`:

```cpp
class HoldsLarge {
public:
  Large GetByValue() const { return l; };

private:
  Large l;
}
```

If I do

```cpp
HoldsLarge x;
func(x.GetByValue());
```

am I correct in understanding that a temporary will be copy constructed for `x.GetByValue()` which will by passed by reference to `func`? Is there something in the standard which will allow a compiler to omit the construction of the temporary altogether? After all, `func` only need a `const` reference to `HoldsLarge::l`.

I understand I could simply return `HoldsLarge::l` by const reference but I would like to prevent clients from accidentally creating a dangling reference.

Comment: It's not avoidable if the signatures can't be changed. Why don't you make another function `GetByConstReference`? (or alternatively use smart pointers `weak_ptr`

Comment: ... also, with threads, it's entirely possible that something modifies the original `x.l` while the function is running. Even without, there might be references to it (as global variables or something) outside and `func` might modify one of them. So that's a behavior change.

Comment: I feel like the worry about dangling references is overblown. Does anyone worry that `std::vector<T>::operator[]` hands out references (or, y'know, `.`)?

Comment: AFAIK, the compiler is not allowed to make this "optimization".  If it did so, then the  function could potentially change the state of `l` by using `const_cast`.  Yes,  `const_cast` is bad, but it gets used wrong all the time.

Comment: @NathanOliver [`[dcl.init]/5.3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#ref-5.3) applies. In the case of `func(x.GetByValue())`, `cv1 = const`, `T1 = Large`, `cv2 =`, `T2 = Large`. `x.GetByValue()` is the converted initializer, and is a prvalue, type `T4 = Large`. Its type is adjusted to `cv1 T4 = Large const`. In the prvalue to xvalue conversion, the temporary object is thus type `Large const`. So as long as `func` doesn't take the argument's address, the proposed optimization is OK, since modification is UB anyway and it's your fault if `x.l` then magically gets mutated. Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: @HTNW: Modifying const **object** is UB, constness of reference is irrelevant so with `HoldsLarge x;`, `func(x.GetByConstRef());` would be allowed to do modification, with `const HoldsLarge x;` it will not. Returning by value allows the modification. Returning by const value would disallow it.

Comment: @Jarod42 If `x.GetByValue()` returns by-value, then, (if I'm reading the standard correctly), when you use it like `func(x.GetByValue())`, because `func` takes a `const&`, the return value of `x.GetByValue()` is indeed constructed into a `const` object: "If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type `T4` is adjusted to type `cv1 T4`", and `cv1` comes from the reference, and it is `const`. Then it's UB to modify that temporary object, because that object is `const`, and that object is `const` because the reference type it was constructed to bind to was `const`.

Comment: I though that the temporary is not const by itself, but only binds to const reference as regular object... :/

Comment: @Jarod42 Honestly, I thought that too, until I decided to read that part of the standard today and apparently it's `const`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is allowed to change behavior (as optimization) in few cases: for NRVO, and since C++14 for new expression.

You are not in those cases.

Then; as-if rule allows any optimizations as long as observable behavior is identical.

So compiler can do the optimization **only if** that doesn't change the behavior.

Without knowing `func`, it cannot safely do that.

`func` might have access to `x.l` (or alias) from another way (as global).

For example, following `func` would prohibit the change.

```
Large* largePtr; // possibly set to &x.l by any way
void func(const Large& param)
{
    print(param.x);
    //param might be alias of largePtr
    mutate(alias->x);
    print(param.x); // const ref should see the modification
                    // whereas copy don't
}
```